# Updating a table structured items

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make it possible for a user to **accept/reject an item** stating a **reason** in any of the items presented in a table with a **PaginatedList**:

```razor
@model PaginatedList<ItemViewModel>

<table>
<thead>
 ...
</thead>

 for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++){
   var item = Model.ElementAt(i);
   ...
  <tr>
     <td><input asp-for="@item.AdditionalText" type="text" /></td>
     <td>
         <form asp-action="AddAdditionalText" method="post" asp-route-trackID="@item.itemID" asp-route-notes="@item.AdditionalText">
              <input value="Accept Item" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
         </form>
     </td>
     <td>
         <form asp-action="AddAdditionalText" method="post" asp-route-trackID="@item.itemID" asp-route-notes="@item.AdditionalText">
              <input value="Reject Item" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
         </form>
     </td>
  <tr>
  ...
```

Data is submitted to the controller and in the action, I see only the itemID being submitted and not the notes. It is null because it is out of form. I tried but it doesn't work. Could you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the notes in the `form` which is being submitted. Keep the input element for the `AdditionalText` in the same form where you submit buttons are. Also keep a name attribute on your submit buttons so that you know which button is clicked, inside your http post action method

```
<form asp-action="AddAdditionalText" method="post" asp-route-trackID="@item.itemID">
     <input asp-for="@item.AdditionalText" type="text" />
     <input value="Accept Item" name="reason" type="submit" class="btn">
     <input value="Reject Item" name="reason" type="submit" class="btn">
</form>
```

and in the action method.

```
public ActionResult AddAdditionalText(int trackId,string AdditionalText, string reason)
{
    if (reason == "Accept Item")
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
    // to do  : return something
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't see this as a specific answer to a table related issue. Also, I have updated my question with the PaginatedList that I'm using.